# How to connect Quorum with Metamask?

Tags: metamask, dapps, quorum

I'm trying to deploy smart contract on Private blockchain(quorum). And run the dapp on private blockchain. But I'm unable to connect the metamask with quorum network. The quorum is currently running on VM.  Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

please edit your VM to expose the RPC port to the host machine. You are also going to need to add cors origin if the guest/host urls are different. See: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Command-Line-Options --rpccorsdomain

Comment: Can you please help me with this.  Because I failed to fix this. How can I expose the RPC port of VM?