# MetaMask - Quorum - Network - Custom RPC - Could not fetch chain ID. Is your RPC URL correct?

Tags: metamask, quorum, configuration, cakeshop

#### Instructions from scratch

https://docs.goquorum.consensys.net/en/latest/Tutorials/Creating-A-Network-From-Scratch/

#### genesis.json

Directly from the tutorial:

`"chainId": 10,`

#### startnode1.sh

`#!/bin/bash`

`PRIVATE_CONFIG=ignore nohup ~/quorum/build/bin/geth --datadir new-node-1 --nodiscover --verbosity 5 --networkid 31337 --raft --raftport 50000 --rpc --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0 --rpcport 22000 --rpcapi admin,db,eth,debug,miner,net,shh,txpool,personal,web3,quorum,raft --emitcheckpoints --port 21000 >> node.log 2>&1 &`

#### node.log

Snippet:

`INFO [10-28|07:05:16.741] Initialised chain configuration          config="{ChainID: 10 Homestead: 0 DAO: <nil> DAOSupport: false EIP150: 0 EIP155: 0 EIP158: 0 Byzantium: 0 IsQuorum: false Constantinople: 0 TransactionSizeLimit: 0 MaxCodeSize: 0 Petersburg: <nil> Istanbul: <nil> PrivacyEnhancements: <nil> Engine: unknown}`

`IsQuorum: false` - unsure?

#### Running cakeshop

https://docs.goquorum.consensys.net/en/latest/HowTo/GetStarted/Cakeshop/

`java -jar cakeshop-0.11.0.war`

[image]

#### I would like to send some transactions to see the block mining process...

http://localhost:8080/manage.html

[image]

It super easy for sure, if you know it. New to the Quorum business. Quorum and Metamask are on the same box, no need to enable CORS: [How to connect Quorum with Metamask?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/62467/how-to-connect-quorum-with-metamask)

**EDIT:** Not sure if that matters but I did `geth --datadir new-node-2 init genesis.json` using the `default geth` not `quorum geth`. See [this issue](https://github.com/ConsenSys/quorum/issues/1091) not sure if that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to have cors enabled for Metamask, even though it's a local node. I suggest enabling cors and trying it.

Note that you must use quorum geth for the `init`. If you use upstream geth then you will run into issues when attempting to use quorum.

Comment: Of course. Thank you for helping. I've enabled `--rpccorsdomain "*"`, added to Matemask and it crashed... `github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/raft.(*minter).mintNewBlock(0xc000276d20)` Thank you for updating the GitHub issue, very helpful!